# Earth Engine: Flatten (?) list of filters for ee.Filter.or

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a more elegant way than calling each filter in the list? It looks like ee.Filter.or wants separate arguments, not a list.

Using var NEfilter = ee.Filter.or(filterlist) gives the error:

**Filter.or, argument 'filters': Invalid type. Expected: List< Filter >. Actual: List< List< Filter >>**

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dffaf31424c0b5cbf2fd69187523eae0

```
var AllStates    = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1fRY18cjsHzDgGiJiS2nnpUU3v9JPDc2HNaR7Xk8');   // U.S. States
print (AllStates);

var NameFcn = function(name) {
  return ee.Filter.eq('Name', name);
  };

var NE_list = ["Massachusetts", "Connecticut", "Rhode Island", "Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire"];
var filterlist = NE_list.map(NameFcn)

print(filterlist)

var NEfilter = ee.Filter.or(filterlist[0],filterlist[1],filterlist[2],filterlist[3],filterlist[4],filterlist[5]);

var NEStates = AllStates.filter(NEfilter);
print(NEStates)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
var AllStates    = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1fRY18cjsHzDgGiJiS2nnpUU3v9JPDc2HNaR7Xk8');   // U.S. States
print (AllStates);

var NameFcn = function(name) {
  return ee.Filter.eq('Name', name);
  };

var NE_list = ["Massachusetts", "Connecticut", "Rhode Island", "Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire"];
var filterlist = NE_list.map(NameFcn)

var filtered = AllStates.filter(ee.Filter.inList('Name', NE_list))
print(filtered)
```

Comment: Yes!  I even saw that one and the word "metadata" in the docs confused me -- assumed it was for image collections.